# Current common practices in web application architecture

Tags: php, architecture

Here's a very broad question:

I've been building a small MVC framework in PHP, mostly for the sake of learning better practices in my coding (and so I have a system to manage my home finances).  In reading up, I've discovered a lot on VOs and DAOs, which were new to me, at least in a formalized way.  This made me realize that even though I've been programming in PHP for a few years, I've only been in one project, and have been kind of isolated.

So I'm familiar with MVC, VO/DAO, and 3-Tier.  My question is, are there other key architecture patterns I might be missing in web application development?  Are there any other common practices or "industry standards", and if so, where are some good places to read up on them? (PHP-specific is a plus)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd also look into code generation/scaffolding/ORM, or ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 1):

[Model-View-Presenter (MVP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter) is a derivative of the MVC pattern. Application of MVP is similar to MVC; it's worth taking a look at and having in your bag of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

well, basically the same patterns as in normal applications apply, with gui patterns for the design and the "usual" patterns for the code. You coul read the gang of four "Design Patterns" book, which covers a lot of ground.
[Here's](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/) a short article with 5 common software design patterns, with php examples

Also, [Common Design Patterns for use in MVC Web Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327701/common-design-patterns-for-use-in-mvc-web-applications)